# Searching DOM elements for ID value in angular

Tags: html, angular

Is there a way to search DOM elements for a specific element ID in angular 4? I am trying to search for an ID of a div in my ngb-accordion inside the ng-template.

I am looking for that Id div id="3005"

```
<ng-template class="super" ngbPanelTitle>
                        <div class="row heads">
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div  [class]="className" id="3005" #mydiv></div>  &nbsp;<b>Just a description</b>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </ng-template>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure you back up your question with a POC or the code you have been working on which will help everyone understand what you are doing. Cheers!

Comment: document.getElementById('_sectionIdHere_'); This returns the corresponding div

Answer (score 0):

you can access your div by using`@ViewChild`.
Please go through [this](https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/).

Comment: tried that but doesnt give me the div id but the control its self. The div id that am looking for is inside the ngb-accordion control

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using querySelector like so:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#3005'))[0]
```

happy coding :)